# which git worklfow is this?(Tag on master and hotfix-branch)

Tags: git, git-flow, git-workflow

in my previous job we  followed a git workflow who seem perfect:

- we had feature branch and a master like usual
- each time we want to deliver we put a tag on the master with a major version name, then deploy the tag on our test env, then preprod, then prod.
- If there was an issue in the tagged version we make an hotfix branch out of it, then create a new tag (with a minor version) of it, who will be deployed, and merge/cherrypick the "hotfix branch" into the master.
- Basicaly, major version tag are on the master, while hotfix version tag are on the hotfix branch.

**what is the name of this workflow ?**

I want to re-use it on my new mission, but I don't know how it's called and I need doc in order to convince my new team.

Answer (score 0):

According to [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you would merge your `hotfix` branch into `master` and then tag `master` with the new minor or hotfix version.

It would then still be called `git-flow`.

The important part here is to understand that `git-flow` is just a framework. You can make some adjustments to meet the requirements in your team and it will still be `git-flow`.

Take Scrum as an example. It's an agile framework but not every team uses it precisely the same way. You have to adjust it to your team but it will still be Scrum.